# Why UserRole implements Serializable and override equals() and hashcode() method

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm

In Grails, Spring security core plugin helps to create User and Role domains.Due to many to many relationship in them 3rd domain UserRole is created.

```
UserRole.groovy

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder

class UserRole implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    User user
    Role role

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (!(other instanceof UserRole)) {
            return false
        }

        other.user?.id == user?.id &&
            other.role?.id == role?.id
    }

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        if (user) builder.append(user.id)
        if (role) builder.append(role.id)
        builder.toHashCode()
    }

    static UserRole get(long userId, long roleId) {
        UserRole.where {
            user == User.load(userId) &&
            role == Role.load(roleId)
        }.get()
    }

    static UserRole create(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
        new UserRole(user: user, role: role).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
    }

    static boolean remove(User u, Role r, boolean flush = false) {

        int rowCount = UserRole.where {
            user == User.load(u.id) &&
            role == Role.load(r.id)
        }.deleteAll()

        rowCount > 0
    }

    static void removeAll(User u) {
        UserRole.where {
            user == User.load(u.id)
        }.deleteAll()
    }

    static void removeAll(Role r) {
        UserRole.where {
            role == Role.load(r.id)
        }.deleteAll()
    }

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['role', 'user']
        version false
    }
}
```

I have never seen or created a domain class that implements Serializable interface.I think grails handles serialization process internally.So why UserRole implements Serializable ? And what is the advantage of overriding equals() and hascode() methods here as the id of UserRole is already composite on User and Role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a requirement of Hibernate when using composite keys; see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid

Comment: I removed Serializable interface and equals hashcode methods from UserRole and tested on both mysql and mongodb.While using mysql with hibernate it gave "org.hibernate.MappingException: composite-id class must implement Serializable".But worked perfectly with mongodb.So I think it only requires when datasourse is hibernate.If I am correct,it should be mention in spring security core plugin docs as this plugin is used by various datasourses.

Comment: By the way,thanks for giving this information.I do not have any knowledge of hibernate and I just know little about Serialization.Still a question remains in my mind. Why hibernate imposed this condition of implementing Serializable interface ?